# Try to make a regex, that match CSV string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, csv

I have this regex - `/^(?:[a-z0-9]+,?)+$/gmi`.
Works perfect, but when string is too large, it freezes page. And i have just an ordinary page with one input. Maybe you know the way how to optimize that, thanks a lot!

Try to find a perfect regex for input, where users can type comma separated values. Also users input should look like "first,second,third".

Thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean CSV, not scv? If so, please fix your title to make it more clear.

Comment: Is the regex intended to *validate* the whole input, or to filter lines to extract the valid ones? Can you give an example input for which it is too slow? Is input really not allowed to include spacing? What about quoted values? What is the javascript code that uses this regex?

Comment: @trincot yes, regex validate whole input,
example: something like firstname,secondname,thirdname... so it is comma separated values, but we can't insert two commas, and can't insert spaces between words,
js code is just e.target.value (which is just value from input).match(regex)
Thanks

Comment: So it is just one line of input? And this is freezing the page? Can you show some code that illustrates this?

Comment: @mg
i can do it, but user will try to paste data, and i will have additional code to hadle that, it can solve a problem, but it recuire more logic

Comment: @trincot sure, https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-sound-jexqny

Comment: I think you have to overwrite the field every time you handle onChange with `found = e.target.value.match(/^((?:[a-z0-9],?)*)/i);` This has to be in the case of trimming Paste text.

Comment: This seems to work  but needs some work `const handleChange = (e) => {
    const found = e.target.value.match(/^(?:[a-z0-9],?)*/i);
    setVal(found );}` since it works good for backspaces and paste but will truncate at the first invalid key  when editing from the middle. It's actually better to handle keystrokes at the caret if thats possible with JS.
    };`

Comment: @rodion if you are parsing user input on input change events, at least look to debounce processing asynchronously! DOM event handlers should terminate as quick as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern is not able to fail quickly when the string doesn't match. The main problem is that the regex engine tries again and again different ways to succeeds (using the backtracking mechanism). Since the comma is optional in your repeated group, there's too many
possible ways to divide word characters between each group repeat, and the regex engine is well decided to try all these possible divisions. Result: [catastrophic backtracking](https://regex101.com/r/yZGMfu/1) (the regex engine uses too many steps to know if yes or not the pattern matches the string.)

You can find several examples with a description in this page: https://javascript.info/regexp-catastrophic-backtracking

Several ways are possible to solve the problem, but I think that using an unrolled design is the more simple way:

```
/^[a-z0-9]+(?:,[a-z0-9]+)*$/i
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/yZGMfu/2)

You can also emulate an atomic group putting the main part of your original pattern into a lookahead and a capture group followed by a reference to the captured content (more complicated, less steps, but perhaps overkill):

```
/^(?=((?:[a-z0-9]+,?)+))\1\b$/i
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/yZGMfu/4)

Answer (score 0):

How about just `^[a-z0-9,]+$`? It doesn't matter where the commas are in relation to the other characters since CSVs can have empty cells (ie 2 commas next to eachother.

Comment: it works, but still can type something like ",,,first,,,second,third"

Comment: @rodion that is valid CSV syntax for putting an empty cell.

Answer (score 0):

I will not directly answer your question because the premise of your problem is not the regular expression but rather the size of your data.

Although, using a regular expression as a parser is not a good design in any case.

Instead of re-inventing the wheel, try to use already existing code, like [Papa parse](https://www.papaparse.com/).

---

#### ** Edit **

From your comment, you can certainly validate user input with a parser. Here is for your consideration.

```js
const Papa = require("papaparse")

// // implement validation here
const validateCSV = line => true;   // param "line" is properly parsed CSV line

const parseString = csv => new Promise(resolve => {
   const data = [];
   Papa.parse(csv, {
      step: (results) => {
         const line = results.data;
         if (validateCSV(line)) {
            data.push(line);
         }
      },
      complete: () => {
         resolve(data);
     }
   });
});


parseString(",,,first,,,second, third\n1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8").then(data => {
    console.log("CSV Data:", data);
});
```

Comment: I second this. Papa parse is fast and easy to use.

Comment: yes, but here i try to prevent user typing of something that doesn't match regex, in my case something like ",,,first,,,second, third" will not work. Thanks for helping

Comment: and also size of my data is just an input from user, so it can't be huge

Comment: @rodion you can do what you ask with a parser. I edited my answer to reflect unwillingness to consider a different perspective. Thank you.